# Tips for cooked chicken to stay juicy half a day

Tags: chicken

A little background: I'm going to build a chicken congee business.

In my country, generally, it's a coconut rice congee poured with turmeric chicken broth. (The chicken breast from the broth will be taken, shredded and placed in a different container and will be used as topping for the congee. If you want to know, the name of the dish is Bubur Ayam.)

My main differentiation will be additional spices for the broth, like star anise and oregano and another things (might be a fusion, but that's too fancy).

My main question is: After being cooked in broth, generally the chicken will be put in a small container, just sitting there for half a day or until sold out (the opening hours will be 6 in the morning to 11.).  
(Without the broth, it's in different container, and the white plain congee is in a third container, on a stove that always has a small fire so the congee is always warm.)

Any tips so the texture and taste won't deteriorate during that time? Should I fry the chicken beforehand?

Oh yeah, the general recipe for the broth: coriander seeds, ginger, lemongrass, shallot, garlic, salt and soysauce. Any other tips will be appreciated .

Comment: Chicken held at room temperature for 2 hours or more will be unsafe to eat.  It must be kept hotter than 60C(or 140F) or lower than 4C(or 40F) to remain free of harmful pathogens.

Comment: @jbarker2160 It's apparent from the question that OP isn't dealing with the notoriously overly-conservative FDA or USDA. Considering that even *those* bureaucracies occasionally let a 4 hour rule slip, it's a bit hasty to slam dunk the OP at 2 hours.

Comment: As you can already see from comments, there is a safety issue here. You've mentioned keeping the congee warm. Will it it stay over 60C? That's important. Can you keep the chicken portion refrigerated or on ice until you warm it to add to the congee at service? That's important too (or keep it over 60C instead, but I'm afraid quality will suffer). I'm not going to shove USDA rules down your throat, but if you're going to sell to the public, you have a responsibility to do it safely.

Comment: @Jolenealaska those rules aren't conservative in the slightest for a street vendor.  Some of my European colleagues suggest that their rules for street vendors are even more strict than that due to the less-controlled nature of the environment and more possibilities of contamination by macroscopic pathogens as well if the food is too cold.

Comment: @jbarker2160 will you meet me in chat?

Answer (score 1):

Brining the chicken in salt will help it maintain it's moisture as well as making it less bio-friendly. It has the side effect of making the chicken taste really good when just plain chicken. If you do this, remove your other salt components from you recipe.